# Sound pops in wireless headphones when using microphone through usb hub

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, usb-hub, wireless-headset

here is the problem:

- HP Probook 650 G5
- Ugreen USB 3.0 Hub / Switcher with 4 ports connected to the laptop
- Wireless headset (Radiofrequency - JBL quantum 600) with USB dongle connected to the USB switcher
- Sound is okay without problem when only listening to youtube or some other source of sound
- When I open Sound Settings, I test the microphone on some website, or I am connected to Skype / Teams / Webex, the output starts to Pop and Crack, I can listen clear but the popping is annoying
- When I press the button to switch to my personal laptop - Acer Predator G15, I test the microphone and everything is fine, I can clearly listen and talk without popping sound
- When I put the USB dongle from the headset directly to the laptop, it works without popping but as I frequently switch between my two laptops I want to have the dongle connected to the USB switcher
- I tried installing drivers, device manager reports no problem, some power management features from official HP site but nothing has resolved that
- on my work laptop - where the problem is, I am using Windows 10 1909 version and on my personal laptop I have 2004 version

Comment: Your tests are conclusive. The problem is using it with the Ugreen switcher. Not surprising, I had 2 Ugreen products completely fail already. And many USB audio devices do have problems with many USB hubs, I not sure why.

Comment: @ChanganAuto but why on one laptop it works flawlessly and second has a problem ? I dont understand that, not enough power is not the issue as I added additional power to the USB hub and nothing has changed